# Restrict scope in acts_as_list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-list

```
class TodoList < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :todo_items, -> { order("position ASC") }
end

class TodoItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :todo_list
  acts_as_list scope: :todo_list
end
```

I would like to restrict the items acts_as_list is managing, not only by the parent association (TodoList) but aswell by items that have the `done_at` attribute present:

```
scope :active, -> { where("done_at is NULL)}
```

How can I add query rules to acts_as_list's scope?